# I cannot receive emails from external domain with virtual users

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, imap, postfix-mta, dovecot

I cannot receive emails from external domains in my ubuntu 18.04 mail server. 
i can send to other domains with my sendgrid relay server since outbound port 25 is blocked by google cloud. i can also receive mails from other virtual users in my domain.

i have unblocked port 110,143,587,993 and 995. i can also telnet on these ports.

i tested my mail server on pingability.com and i got ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) for POP3

i got ProtocolException: No login methods supported! for IMAP

Answer (score 0):

it was my ignorance. i learnt that both incoming and outgoing mail requires port 25 to be open. if outgoing port is blocked, you can use a smtp relay service.

my solution was opening incoming connection on port 25 using google cloud firewall rules